# Repeating UIImage

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, tiles

I have a `UIImage` I need to repeat(tile) to fill a bigger size. the size doesn't have to be a multiple of the original image the result should be `CGImage` because thats what I will eventually use, but if making `UIImage` is faster/easier its ok too.
How can I do this?

Comment: UIColor has a class method called +(UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image, I'm not writing this as an answer because it doesn't exactly solve your question, but it might help you.

Comment: Actually that seems to exactly answer his question as far as I can tell... colorWithPatternImage will tile just like he is asking.